# Why can't I parse this SOAP response with SimpleXML?

Tags: xml, soap, simplexml

I've been searching for a solution for this for hours but nothing seems to work, I've read http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/ but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the xml I'm trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <FlokkurResponse xmlns="http://www2.ksi.is/vefthjonustur/mot/">
      <FlokkurSvar>
        <ArrayFlokkur>
          <Flokkur>
            <FlokkurHeiti>1. flokkur</FlokkurHeiti>
            <FlokkurNumer>113</FlokkurNumer>
          </Flokkur>
          <Flokkur>
            <FlokkurHeiti>2. flokkur</FlokkurHeiti>
            <FlokkurNumer>109</FlokkurNumer>
          </Flokkur>
          <Flokkur>
            <FlokkurHeiti>3. flokkur</FlokkurHeiti>
            <FlokkurNumer>124</FlokkurNumer>
          </Flokkur>
        </ArrayFlokkur>
        <VillaNumer>0</VillaNumer>
      </FlokkurSvar>
    </FlokkurResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I want to do is get the value of each FlokkurHeiti so I thought I could do this:

```
foreach ($xml->Flokkur as $x) {
    echo $x->FlokkurHeiti.'<br/>';
}
```

As you can see neither FLokkur nor FlokkurHeiti have any namespaces or attributes but I don't get any output.

I've also tried

```
$t = $xml->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")->Body->FlokkurResponse->children("http://www2.ksi.is/vefthjonustur/mot/")->FlokkurSvar->ArrayFlokkur->Flokkur;
foreach ($t as $x) {
    echo $x->FlokkurHeiti.'<br/>';
}
```

But get Node no longer exist warning

Can someone help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see neither FLokkur nor FlokkurHeiti have any namespaces

Actually, they **have** a namespace : `xmlns="http://www2.ksi.is/vefthjonustur/mot/"`

Maybe you could have a look to : http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/